# Importing new LibGDX project to Android Studio, Stuck at Gradle Build

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I went to the libGDX website and downloaded the gdx-setup.jar file.  I opened it, configured it and clicked generate.  It generated the gradle project successfully.  I then went to Android Studio -> Open an existing project -> pointed to the new libgdx gradle project.  It is stuck at "Building 'gdxgame' Gradle project info"

I let it run for over an hour with no results.  I checked task manager and CPU usage is 0% for the process AndroidStudio.

I had API 22 and 23.  I then decided to get the recommended version "20" along with build tools version 20.  gdx-setup failed to generate in any configuration except the following:

Build-Tools - Latest in system (23)

API-version - 20

So, whats messed up?  I have the latest version of Android Studio (1.3.2 build 141.2178183)

Comment: What do you mean by "Open an existing project -> pointed to the new libgdx gradle project."? Did you try to open the build.gradle file in the root folder of your project?

Comment: He he... yea I did that and now its working.  previously I just pointed to the directory.  Anyways, now it opens up but a new error saying "could not resolve lwjgl in desktop\build.gradle" appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I was supposed to point to "build.gradle" file for importing.  I was choosing the directory and it got stuck.  Now it works.  Thanks to noone for pointing that out.